# Capture Click Event from dynamically added HTML after ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, leaflet, ionic3, leaflet.markercluster

I am developing an Ionic 3 app that implements [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) library. The app is designed to run in offline mode. The map is being rendered on `ngOnInit()` invocation.

The map has Marker cluster added and each marker has a HTML popup when clicked as follows:

```
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<div  class=\"marker-title\"></div><p>" + title + "</p>");
```

I would like to capture a click event when the **'marker-title'** is tapped.

Problem is the adding normal Angular click binding on the HTML string does not fire - as it is added after the entire DOM has been rendered and Angular could not register it.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have your tried `Renderer`?

Answer (score 0):

Listening to document will capture all events, even if it is ugly to use in angular

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // if e.target is your element do something
});
```